# What prevents me for being able to publish a .net MAUI application on IOS from a mac?

Tags: ios, maui, code-signing

I am getting issues publishing my .Net MAUI app on iOS. It looks related to the signing process but I am stuck.

Here is part of the output when using diagnose mode:

```
  ...
  ...
09:41:54.521     2>Cible "_DetectSigningIdentity : (IdCible:56)" dans le fichier "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7067/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets" du projet "/Users/david/Private/Projects/maui-jass/MauiJass.csproj" (la cible "_CoreCompileImageAssets" en dépend) :
                   Utilisation de la tâche "DetectSigningIdentity" à partir de l'assembly "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7067/tools/msbuild/iOS/../iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.dll".
                   Tâche "DetectSigningIdentity" (IDTâche:31)
                     Paramètre de tâche :CodesignProvision=jass (IDTâche:31)
                     Paramètre de tâche :ProvisioningProfile=jass (IDTâche:31)
                     Paramètre de tâche :RequireCodeSigning=True (IDTâche:31)
                     Paramètre de tâche :SdkPlatform=iPhoneOS (IDTâche:31)
                     Paramètre de tâche :SdkIsSimulator=False (IDTâche:31)
                     Paramètre de tâche :BundleIdentifier=ch.jass.maui (IDTâche:31)
                     Paramètre de tâche :AppBundleName=MauiJass (IDTâche:31)
                     Paramètre de tâche :TargetFrameworkMoniker=.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0,Profile=ios (IDTâche:31)
                     Paramètre de tâche :SigningKey=Apple Distribution: DAVID XXXXXX (46F9H8K4Y5) (IDTâche:31)
09:41:54.533     2>/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7067/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1714,3): error : ASN1 corrupted data. [/Users/david/Private/Projects/maui-jass/MauiJass.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-ios]
                     Propriété en sortie : _AppIdentifier=ch.jass.maui (IDTâche:31)
                     Propriété en sortie : _CodesignAllocate=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate (IDTâche:31)
                     Propriété en sortie : _DistributionType=Any (IDTâche:31)
                   Exécution de la tâche "DetectSigningIdentity" terminée -- ÉCHEC. (IDTâche:31)
09:41:54.534     2>Génération de la cible "_DetectSigningIdentity" terminée dans le projet "MauiJass.csproj" -- ÉCHEC. : (IdCible:56)
09:41:54.534     2>Génération du projet "/Users/david/Private/Projects/maui-jass/MauiJass.csproj" terminée (Publish cible(s)) -- ÉCHEC.
09:41:54.534     1>Exécution de la tâche "MSBuild" terminée -- ÉCHEC. (IDTâche:3)
09:41:54.534     1>Génération de la cible "Publish" terminée dans le projet "MauiJass.sln" -- ÉCHEC. : (IdCible:5)
09:41:54.534     1>Génération du projet "/Users/david/Private/Projects/maui-jass/MauiJass.sln" terminée (Publish cible(s)) -- ÉCHEC.
```

Ending with this error:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7067/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1714,3): error : ASN1 corrupted data. [/Users/david/Private/Projects/maui-jass/MauiJass.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-ios]
```

I've found a couple related threads suggesting either to delete bin/obj and retry, or to not put the signing properties into the `.csproj` file but directly through command line. I tried both ways and still get the same results.

Another one suggesting to recreate from scratch certificates and provisioning profiles. I removed all certificates from keychain and imported new ones. I am still not able to go one step further.

It also looks to happen with a brand new .net Maui project.

One more note: the bundle signing tab is empty even in a new project:
[image]

I am able to run the app in debug mode without issues. I am able to publish on android but not ios.

I am running latest version of Visual Studio 2022 for MAC (17.6) and have applied all latest XCode updates, etc.

Not sure what could be wrong at this point.

Comment: The Bundle Signing window should not be empty. Check your .cproj file. Probably there are some issues over there. If you dont know what's going wrong, compare the cproj file with a new one.

Comment: Unfortunately the bundle signing window is empty even with a brand new project !

Comment: So, as it's empty copy/paste the section to your project by replacing the current one. The window should appear with empty contents. In case that even now it's not working you can always add the correct values to the .cproj file. Many times i had to kill VS on mac and reopen the project in order the values to appear too.